# Returning results not displayed with typeahead

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have gone through every solution about this post on stackoverflow, none of them solved my problem,

I have implemented `typeahead.js` successfully but and I am getting proper result but results are not displaying in drop down.

```
<input type="text" name="suggest" id="suggest" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="type your message">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#suggest').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://chat.synetal.com/Suggestion/getMsg",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    result($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: do you get response from server?

Comment: yes this the response ["hi how are you","100000","welcome to kuber support"]�

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with jquery autocomplete

[From this URL i have completed this and its easy to impletment](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)